# Importing xlsx file with space in filename in Stata .do file

Tags: excel, filenames, stata

I am totally new to Stata and am wondering how to import `.xlsx` data in Stata. Let's say the data is in the subdirectory Data and has name "a b c.xlsx". So, from working directory, the data is in `/Data`

I am trying to do 
`import excel using "\Data\a b c.xlsx", sheet("a")`

but it's not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it's not working

is anything but a useful error report. For future questions, please report the exact error given by Stata.

Let's say the file is in the directory `/home/roberto` then

```
clear 
set more off

import excel using "/home/roberto/a b c.xlsx"

list
```

should work.

If you are already in `/home/roberto` (which you can verify using `display c(pwd)`), then

```
import excel using "a b c.xlsx"
```

should work.

Using backslashes to refer to directories is not encouraged. See [Stata tip 65: Beware the backstabbing backslash](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0042), by Nick Cox.

See also `help cd`.